# How to define multiple types depending on the property name of an object

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a browser extension and in order to communicate between background and frontend I need to use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`

In my frontend script, I want to send a message to the background, so I do this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'setUpdate', value: { total: 4, alarm: false }  })
```

And in the background I receive it like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message: BackgroundMessage) => {
  switch (message.action) {
     case 'setUpdate':
        ...
     break;
  }
});
```

My problem is creating the `BackgroundMessage` type, as each `action` will have a different value type.

I've tried this:

```
interface actions {
  setUpdate: { total: number; alarm: boolean };
  setReminder: { text: string; when: Date };
}

type BackgroundMessage = Record<keyof actions, actions>;
```

But I don't know how to specify that the keys of the action interface need to be in the `action` property, and the value types in the `value` property.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have defined a map of actions to values, so you could use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to make a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) from that map:

```
interface Actions {
  setUpdate: { total: number; alarm: boolean };
  setReminder: { text: string; when: Date };
}

type BackgroundMessage = {
    [K in keyof Actions]: { action: K; value: Actions[K] };
}[keyof Actions];
```

Then you can narrow the type based on the action:

```
if (msg.action === "setReminder") {
    msg.value.text // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRza1w)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! One question, why is the `[keyof Actions]` required at the end of the type declaration?

Comment: @Cornwell The mapped type produces an object, so you need to get the values of the object like that.